# How to copy data from one table into another in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I'm working on quite a complex for which I do need your advice.
I need to copy data from one table to another table, and I know that for this approach, there are quite a few solutions like

### If both are the same schema

```
INSERT INTO newTable
SELECT * FROM oldTable
```

### If both are a different schema

```
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM oldTable
```

A `SQL Cursor` can also be used, and a lot more variations does exists.
But let me summarize the problem:

### The problem

I do have a CSV file which contains approx. 1.5 million records. Each record currently has 6 fields which are being imported.

Now, to insert the data from the CSV file into SQL server, I'm using C# in combination with Entity Framework.

For performance, I'll insert all those records in a temporary table.
This is the schema of the temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEMP_GENERIC_ARTICLE](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GlnCode] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [VendorId] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [VendorName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ItemNumber] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ItemUOM] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DateCreatedInternal] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateUpdatedInternal] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TEMP_GENERIC_ARTICLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Then I do have a table which another application will consume, called `T_GENERIC_ARTICLE` which schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_GENERIC_ARTICLE](
    [GlnCode] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [VendorId] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [VendorName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ItemNumber] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [ItemUOM] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.T_GENERIC_ARTICLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [GlnCode] ASC,
    [VendorId] ASC,
    [ItemNumber] ASC,
    [ItemUOM] ASC
)
```

So, the **real** table doesn't have the 'ID' field anymore and has primary key which spans 4 columns on the database.

Now, what I would like to do:

As soon as the data is stored in the `Temp` table, or every 1000 records for example, I need to run a SQL Stored Procedure which will copy the data from the `temp` table to the `destination` table.

Upon the copy, I need to check wether a record with that primary key is already existing. If that's the case, then I would like to update the record, otherwise I want to insert a new record.

After the copy has been fully done I would like to remove all the records in the `temp` table.

### The question

What's the best approach to work which such a large data set (1.5 million records) in order to transfer the records from the `temp`, to the `destination` table as performant and as fast as possible?

I've never worked with such a large data sets so I really need some advice on this one.

Kind regards

Comment: Why don't you import the data directly from the csv to the target table?

Comment: Probably should be done through an application.

Comment: But you can use SSIS as well just for your info.

Comment: SSIS Is perfectly capable of handling data from csv, and 1.5 million records is hardly breakfast for sql server. Even if this process is done repeatedly, I don't see a reason to write c# code and use another table in the process.

Comment: 1.5 mil record not so large for this task, all the more so for processing in one instance. This task may be done with `MERGE` command in one step with appropriate time i suppose. As it said in comment before, it is easier to merge data directly from CSV. With SSIS if your do this regualry, or with `BULK INSERT` and `MERGE` if it is once-only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026501/bulk-insert-with-csv-file-in-sql-server

Comment: The problem is that I don't need to do an insert only. If I need to check everytime that the record does exists, it's very time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) to copy the data from the staging table to the main table, there should be no problem handling 1.5m rows:

```
MERGE [dbo].[T_GENERIC_ARTICLE] AS t
USING [TEMP_GENERIC_ARTICLE] AS s
    ON s.GlnCode = t.GlnCode
    AND s.VendorId = t.VendorId
    AND s.ItemNumber = t.ItemNumber
    AND s.ItemUOM = t.ItemUOM
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE    
    SET Description = s.Description,
        VendorName = s.VendorName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (GlnCode, Description, VendorId, VendorName, ItemNumber, ItemUOM)
    VALUES (s.GlnCode, s.Description, s.VendorId, s.VendorName, s.ItemNumber, s.ItemUOM);
```

SSIS is good for the insert but it does not handle the upsert very well, as the OLEDB command task operates RBAR, so it is much more efficient to insert to a staging table, and use MERGE than it is to try to upsert directly to the main table.

---

**EDIT**

To answer the question in the comment:

> Does it to a check before inserting every record? or does it do the check only on the first time? I mean, if the merge command does insert a record first, for the following record, will it check if it's existing in the destination table again (since a new record has been added from the previous merge statement)?

It does the check first, but if you have two matching rows in your source table, then the MERGE will fail with the error message

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.

If you have duplicate rows in your temp table you will need to de-dupe them before you perform the merge, so, if you only want the latest record from the temp table for example then you could use `NOT EXISTS` to exlcude records where a new one exists for the same key:

```
WITH LatestTempGenericArticle AS
(
    SELECT  GlnCode, Description, VendorId, VendorName, ItemNumber, ItemUOM
    FROM    dbo.[TEMP_GENERIC_ARTICLE] AS t
    WHERE   NOT EXISTS
            (   SELECT  1
                FROM    dbo.[TEMP_GENERIC_ARTICLE] AS t2
                WHERE   t2.GlnCode = t.GlnCode
                AND     t2.VendorId = t.VendorId
                AND     t2.ItemNumber = t.ItemNumber
                AND     t2.ItemUOM = t.ItemUOM
                AND     t2.DateCreatedInternal > t.DateCreatedInternal
            )
)
MERGE [dbo].[T_GENERIC_ARTICLE] AS t
USING LatestTempGenericArticle AS s
    ON s.GlnCode = t.GlnCode
    AND s.VendorId = t.VendorId
    AND s.ItemNumber = t.ItemNumber
    AND s.ItemUOM = t.ItemUOM
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE    
    SET Description = s.Description,
        VendorName = s.VendorName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (GlnCode, Description, VendorId, VendorName, ItemNumber, ItemUOM)
    VALUES (s.GlnCode, s.Description, s.VendorId, s.VendorName, s.ItemNumber, s.ItemUOM);
```

Comment: I do believe that this is what I need. Give me some time to test the implementation and if everything is working, I'll accept the answer. Otherwise, you'll see a comment on this post from me :-)

Comment: I do have a small question regarding the solution that you proposed. When you're using the `Merge` command. Does it to a check before inserting every record? or does it do the check only on the first time? I mean, if the `merge` command does insert a record first, for the following record, will it check if it's existing in the destination table again (since a new record has been added from the previous `merge` statement)?

Comment: Thanks for your very valuable feedback (the update on your answer). I've opted for the solution to change my temp table using the same primary keys as my destination table. That way I'm always sure that the `merge` command will succeed.